# how to listen asynchronously in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, http

Is it possible to make asynchronous tcp listen in bash script?
Please could you provide a simple example of doing that or a link that describes same thing.

Comment: trying to listen on any port asynchronously, does 'netcat' do that by the way? or it's synchronous?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in bash? An asynchronous listen by itself is essentially useless, you need a persistent bind on a socket if you want to ever catch an incoming SYN. Maybe you should look into xinetd?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky irc client (we'll call it stackirc) as an example (using telnet, but you could just as easily choose to use netcat or bash's inbuilt /dev/tcp handling)  You will need telnet and Xdialog to use it, but It basically just spawns a child shell to watch a file (using Xdialog --tailbox...) that is later updated by telnet.  In this example, I used standard pipes, but it might be more adaptable and clear if named pipes were used instead.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo starting irc > $HOME/.irclog
eval `Xdialog --stdout --separator " " --3inputsbox "setup" 0 0 \
        "USER=" "stackuser-$RANDOM" \
        "SERVER=" "irc.freenode.net" \
        "CHANNEL=" "#stackoverflow" \
      |while read USER SERVER CHANNEL; do
        echo SERVER=\"$SERVER\" USER=\"$USER\" CHANNEL=\"$CHANNEL\"
        break
    done`
#this is where we will get our asynchronous data
Xdialog --title "$CHANNEL irc" --tailbox $HOME/.irclog 30 99 &
XDPID=$!
A='NICK '$USER'
USER '$USER' +iw '$USER' :ashirc
JOIN '$CHANNEL' '$USER
while ([ "$A" ]) do   echo "$A" #this sends the data to the pipe at the end
    A=`Xdialog --timeout 200 --stdout --title "AshIRC message dialog" \
        --inputbox "Enter an IRC message for $CHANNEL" 0 0`
   case $? in
      255)A=PONG;;
      1)kill $XDPID;;
      0)echo $USER:$A >> $HOME/.irclog #see our messages too
        A='PRIVMSG '"$CHANNEL"' :'"$A"'.';; 
   esac
done | telnet $SERVER 6667 | while read LINE; do
    echo ${LINE%%!*}:${LINE#:*:}
done>> $HOME/.irclog
```